# How to fix proguard? Unable to build signed apk with proguard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I tried to make build with -ignorewarnings but that seems to remove all other warnings also, entered required proguard for retrofit also.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 
'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0' 
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'   
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0' 
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0' 
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0' 
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.2.3') {
    transitive = true
}
// Logging interceptor
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4' 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1' 
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0' 
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha11"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:+'
implementation 'com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:9.3.02'
implementation('com.moengage:moengage-segment-integration:3.3.00') {
    transitive = true
}

}
```

Release build should be made but there is some issue with my proguard configuration, i am unable to identify the issue. Please help.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    ... 6 more

Comment: Any class Duplicate with other ?

Comment: No i don't find any, also won't it give some error other than this also if there was a duplicate class, right ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya - yes there are duplicate classes now i can see, thanks
but how do i remove these duplicate classes now, can you help?

Reading library jar [/Users/deepakrathi/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext]
[javax.xml.namespace.QName]
 [javax.xml.XMLConstants]
 [org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory]
 [org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer]
 [org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser]
 [org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException]
 [org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver]

Comment: Which class are duplicate ?

Comment: Search "Already present" Word.

Comment: Done with the duplicate classes, but there are some other issues like - there were 1 references to unknown classes. You should check your configuration for typos.

Comment: you have to add an ignore to your proguard for external libraries

Comment: You can ignore it, because it is the warning I think.

Comment: Note: com.bumptech.glide.Glide: can't find dynamically referenced class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl
Note: kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationsKt: can't find dynamically referenced class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations
Note: kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationsKt: can't find dynamically referenced class kotlin.internal.JRE8PlatformImplementations
Note: kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationsKt: can't find dynamically referenced class kotlin.internal.JRE7PlatformImplementations

Comment: These are the issues left now i think